# Problemas com envio de video para ftp

Tags: android, upload, ftp, vídeo

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class CameraReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Cursor cursor;
    private MetodosUtils metodosUtils = new MetodosUtils();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if ((metodosUtils.IsWifiConnection(context) == true) || (metodosUtils.IsMobileConnection(context) == true)) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    metodosUtils.ftpUpload("ftp.exemplo.com.br", "user", "pass", "/Dados", cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(3))
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

O método ftpUpload:

```
public boolean ftpUpload(String server, String username, String password, String diretorio, String filePath, String fileName) {
        boolean retorno = false;
        boolean dirExists = true;
        FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        String[] fileExists;
        FTPFile[] ftpFile;
        long filesizeLocal = 0;
        long filesizeFtp = 0;

        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                mFTPClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
                mFTPClient.connect(server);
                int reply = mFTPClient.getReplyCode();
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                    mFTPClient.disconnect();
                    retorno = false;
                }
                if (!mFTPClient.login(username, password)) {
                    mFTPClient.logout();
                }
                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                mFTPClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(500);
                mFTPClient.login(username, password);
                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.setBufferSize(1024000);

                String[] directories = diretorio.split("/");
                for (String dir : directories) {
                    if (!dir.isEmpty()) {
                        if (dirExists) {
                            dirExists = mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);
                        }
                        if (!dirExists) {
                            if (!mFTPClient.makeDirectory(dir)) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Não é possível criar diretório remoto '" +
                                        mFTPClient.getReplyString() + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            if (!mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(dir)) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Não é possível acessar o diretório remoto recém-criado '" +
                                        mFTPClient.getReplyString() + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(diretorio);
                fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                fileExists = mFTPClient.listNames();
                filesizeLocal = file.length();
                ftpFile = mFTPClient.listFiles(fileName);
                if (ftpFile.length == 1 && ftpFile[0].isFile()) {
                    filesizeFtp = ftpFile[0].getSize();
                }
                // somente executa se o arquivo não existir ou for menor que o que vai ser enviado.
                if ((Arrays.asList(fileExists).contains(fileName) == false) ||
                        ((Arrays.asList(fileExists).contains(fileName) == true) &&
                                (filesizeLocal > filesizeFtp))) {
                    if (mFTPClient.storeFile(fileName, fis) == true) {
                        retorno = true;
                    } else {
                        mFTPClient.deleteFile(fileName);
                        retorno = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    retorno = true; // se o arquivo já existe com mesmo tamanho exclui a pendencia
                }
                fis.close();
                mFTPClient.logout();
                mFTPClient.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error uploading " + " - " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            retorno = true;
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <class android:name=".CameraReceiver" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.CameraReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
                <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_VIDEO" />
                <action android:name="com.android.camera.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Da forma como está funciona perfeitamente para fotos tirada com a câmera, o problema está nos vídeos, pois após gravado com a camera, o mesmo é enviado sem a extensão para o FTP. E se colocar a extensão manualmente no arquivo, o mesmo não abre.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: @math... desculpa incomodar, mas você que sempre tem me ajudado saberia o que poderia ser esse problema?

Comment: @ramaral... desculpa incomodar, mas você que também sempre tem me ajudado saberia o que poderia ser esse problema?